# Find a file when running shiny

Tags: r, directory, shiny

I have a file that I am having trouble reading in shiny. My user-interface is working fine, but I think my issue is that it's not reading the data when running the app. I am setting my work directory to Desktop. To open the csv file being placed into the code, it is opened by:

```
publishers <- read.csv("App-1/data/syndicationshiny.csv")
```

Then after running the code, I am struggling with running the app:

```
runApp("App-1")

"Warning in file(file, "rt") :
  cannot open file 'data/syndicationshiny.csv': No such file or directory
Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection"
```

So I am able to open it in R, I've already tested that but when I try to run it in the app it can't seem to find it. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Code:

```
# server.R
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
publishers <- read.csv("App-1/data/syndicationshiny.csv")
source("helpers.R")
head(publishers)
publishers$Date_Delivered<-as.Date(publishers$Date_Delivered,'%m/%d/%Y')


shinyServer(
  function(input, output) {
    output$map <- renderPlot({
      data <- switch(input$var, 
                     "A" = publishers[ which(publishers$Publisher=='A'),],
                     "B" = publishers[ which(publishers$Publisher=='B'),],
                     "C" = publishers[ which(publishers$Publisher=='C'),],
                     "D" = publishers[ which(publishers$Publisher=='D'),],
                     "E" = publishers[which(publishers$Publisher=='E'),],
                     "F" = publishers[  which(publishers$Publisher=='F')])

  color <- switch(input$var, 
                  "A" = "darkgreen",
                  "B" = "black",
                  "C" = "darkorange",
                  "D" = "darkviolet",
                  "E" = "darkred",
                  "F" ="darkblue")

  legend <- switch(input$var, 
                   "A" = "A",
                   "B" = "B",
                   "C" = "C",
                   "D" = "D",
                   "E" = "E",
                   "F" ="F")


      g<-ggplot(data,aes(data[,Date_Delivered],data[,impressions], 
                     color = color, 
                       legend.title = legend))+geom_line()
      print(g)
})})

##ui
library(shiny)
shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Syndication"),

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      helpText("Create Graphs on Syndication Publishers"),

      selectInput("var", 
                  label = "Choose a variable to display",
                  choices = c("A", "B",
                              "C", "D","E","F"),
                  selected = "A")),

    mainPanel(plotOutput("map"))
  )
)
)
```

Comment: what is folder/file  structure of your application?

Comment: Could you post your shiny code?

Comment: @PauloMiraMor just posted the code.

Comment: Are you sure the path is correct?

Comment: The path to find the file? @PauloMiraMor

Comment: Yes, the path to the file.

Comment: I think that may be the problem. I am trying to look into it. So tell me what you think: I have my work directory as Desktop. To call the file I have the path: App-1/data/syndicationshiny.csv. That file does open in R. Then when I run the app. I call runApp("App-1"). Does that seem right? @PauloMiraMor

Comment: I don't think it is right. Try changing your file (syndicationshiny.csv) to your working working folder, (App-1) it should stay in the same folder as your `server.R` and  `ui.R` files. And also change your code to `publishers <- read.csv("syndicationshiny.csv")`.

Comment: It still didn't work and I feel like it has to be some minor problem. I now set my work directory to App-1. Within the folder, I have the server, ui, and csv file. I can open the csv file when using that directory. Then when I run runApp("App-1"), it says "Error in shinyAppDir(x) : No Shiny application exists at the path "App-1" @PauloMiraMor

Comment: Don't change the working directory to App-1. Keep the files where they are and the use working directory as Desktop.  Then execute `runApp("App-1")`.

Comment: Yeah but then to call the csv file I need to change it to read.csv("App-1/syndication.csv" @PauloMiraMor I'll give you multiple votes up if this can be figured out haha

Comment: Not really, I guess. Did you try running keeping the path as `read.csv("syndication.csv")`?

Comment: I did and you were right with that I think. So after that worked, when I run it, the error states: "Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'Date_Delivered' not found" so I am wondering if it is actually reading it. Do you see anything in the code that may cause this? @PauloMiraMor Thank you for your help by the way

Comment: OK, the initial problem was solved. Now I guess you have a problem with your `ggplot` call. You are no subsetting correctly. Try:       `g<-ggplot(data,aes(data$Date_Delivered,data$impressions, 
                     color = color, 
                       legend.title = legend))+geom_line()`

Comment: OK, the initial problem was solved. Now I guess you have a problem with your `ggplot` call. You are no subsetting correctly. Try:       `g<-ggplot(data,aes(data$Date_Delivered,data$impressions, 
                     color = color, 
                       legend.title = legend))+geom_line()`

Comment: I've tried that and the error that comes up is: 'Error: object of type 'closure' is not subsettable" @PauloMiraMor

Comment: R is misinterpreting `data`. Instead of an object, it is interpreting it as the function `data()`. Change the name of the object to something else, like `dat` in all it's appearences.

Comment: Doing dat doesn't work. When I change everything that says "data" to "dat" the error comes up: "Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'dat' not found" @PauloMiraMor

Comment: Would you mind posting a sample of `syndication.csv`, so that I would be able to try on my own? That would be much easier.

Comment: Yeah sure, is there a way to attach files on here? @PauloMiraMor

Comment: I'm afraid not. But we could try moving to the chat. This way you can upload the file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87020/discussion-between-paulo-miramor-and-nick).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The path to the file is not correct. Consider that the app is running in the App-1 directory. So use:

```
publishers <- read.csv("data/syndicationshiny.csv")
```

Another problem in your code is the call to `ggplot`. You don't have to use subsetting, just enter the column names.

Also, the way you are using the `color` and `legend` arguments is wrong. From what I could understand, you want each publisher to have a different color legend label. The `colour` argument is used to enter the column by wich the lines will be colored and the legend is produced accordingly.

You can use `scale_color_manual` to use default line colors. This way you can get rid of your `color` and `legend` arguments.

By the way, I suggest not creating objects using function names, such as `data` or `legend`. This can lead to some confusion.

Finally, the code (`ui.R` is as you posted):

```
# server.R
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
publishers <- read.csv("data/syndicationshiny.csv")
#source("helpers.R")
head(publishers)
publishers$Date_Delivered<-as.Date(publishers$Date_Delivered,'%m/%d/%Y')


shinyServer(
  function(input, output) {
    output$map <- renderPlot({
      dat <- switch(input$var, 
                    "A" = publishers[which(publishers$Publisher=='A'),],
                    "B" = publishers[which(publishers$Publisher=='B'),],
                    "C" = publishers[which(publishers$Publisher=='C'),],
                    "D" = publishers[which(publishers$Publisher=='D'),],
                    "E" = publishers[which(publishers$Publisher=='E'),],
                    "F" = publishers[which(publishers$Publisher=='F'),])

      g<-ggplot(dat,aes(Date_Delivered,impressions, 
                        colour = Publisher))+geom_line()+ 
        scale_color_manual(values = c("A" = "darkgreen", 
                                      "B" = "black", 
                                      "C" = "darkorange",
                                      "D" = "darkviolet",
                                      "E" = "darkred",
                                      "F" ="darkblue"
        ))
      g
    })})
```